# Symfony2 One-to-many edit action

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

I have a problem with mu one-to-many relationships in Symfony2.
I have Company and User classes. One company has a few users as an HR and some users have company-employer.
There are parts of code:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company", inversedBy="hrs")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $employer;
....
....
....
    /**
     * Set employer
     *
     * @param \JobFyBundle\Entity\Company $employer
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmployer(\JobFyBundle\Entity\Company $employer = null)
    {
        $this->employer = $employer;
        $employer->addHrs($this);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get employer
     *
     * @return \JobFyBundle\Entity\Company 
     */
    public function getEmployer()
    {
        return $this->employer;
    }
}
```

It's a part of Company class

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CompanyRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="jobfy_company")
 */
class Company {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
...
...
...
/**
     * Add hrs
     *
     * @param User $hr
     * @return Company
     * @internal param User $hrs
     */
    public function addHrs(\JobFyBundle\Entity\User $hr)
    {
        $this->getHrs()->add($hr);
        $hr->setEmployer($this);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove hrs
     *
     * @param \JobFyBundle\Entity\User $hrs
     */
    public function removeHr(\JobFyBundle\Entity\User $hrs)
    {
        $this->hrs->removeElement($hrs);
    }

    /**
     * Get hrs
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getHrs()
    {
        return $this->hrs;
    }
}
```

I try to make edit action to allow adding more hr's.

Here is part of CompanyController:

```
/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing Company entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="company_edit")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Company $company)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($company);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('JobFyBundle\Form\CompanyType', $company, array('csrf_protection' => false));
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $people = $em->getRepository('JobFyBundle:User')->findAll();

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($company);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('company_show', array('id' => $company->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('company/edit.html.twig', array(
        'company' => $company,
        'hrs' => $people,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

And it's a template of edit action.

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <form name="company" method="post" class="form-new">
            <h1 class="form-new-heading">Edit company</h1>
            <div id="cv">
                <div>
                    <label for="company_title">Company title</label>
                    <textarea id="company_title" name="company[title]" class="form-control" 
                              required autofocus>{{ company.title }}</textarea>
                    <label for="company_url">Company url</label>
                    <textarea id="company_url" name="company[url]" class="form-control"
                        >{{ company.url }}</textarea>
                    <label for="company_about_us">About us</label>
                    <textarea id="company_about_us" name="company[about_us]"
                              class="form-control" rows="15">{{ company.getAboutUs }}</textarea>
                    <div>
                        <label for="company_hrs">HRs</label>
                        <select id="company_hrs" name="company[hrs][]" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
                            {% for hr in hrs %}
                                <option value="{{ hr.id }}"
                                        {% if hr.employer is not null and hr.employer.id == company.id %}
                                            selected="selected"
                                        {% endif %}
                                >{{ hr }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <h3><a href="{{ path('company_index_paginate') }}">Show companies list</a></h3>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Everything works, except adding or editing hr's list.
Thank you for help!

Comment: `$hrs` is an [arrayCollection](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html), do you set this in your `__construct()` of the `Company` entity? `public function __construct() { $this->hrs = new ArrayCollection(); }`

Comment: No, I didn't. I set it now, but, unfortunately, it didn't help. But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved a problem.

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Company $company)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($company);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('JobFyBundle\Form\CompanyType', $company, array('csrf_protection' => false));
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $people = $em->getRepository('JobFyBundle:User')->findAll();

    foreach ($company->getHrs() as $hr){
        $company->removeHr($hr);
    }

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        foreach ($_POST['company']['hrs'] as $hr_id){
            $hr = $em->getRepository('JobFyBundle:User')->find($hr_id);
            $company->addHrs($hr);
            $hr->setEmployer($company);
        }

        $em->persist($company);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('company_show', array('id' => $company->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('company/edit.html.twig', array(
        'company' => $company,
        'hrs' => $people,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

It can be useful for somebody, so I'll leave it there :)